# Vue emit (did not listen the emitting event from the child)

Tags: vue.js, events, emit

I am a beginner and I tried vue emit event.  But the event do not listen from the parent. Please Help Me!!

**In App.vue**

```
<app-header v-bind:somethings='name' @custom-event-name="setName"></app-header> 

setName(childName){
 this.name= childName;
```

}

**In Body.vue**

```
<button @click="changeName"> click me to change name </button>

changeName: function(){
        this.$emit('custom-event-name', 'Some Value');    }
```

Comment: How is the `app-header` component imported?

Comment: Are you importing and using the `Body` component too?

Comment: I imported app-header as the following bro @

`<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue';

export default {

 components:{
  'app-header': Header,
  
 },

  data () {
    return {
      name: 'John',
     
    }
  },
  methods: {

   setName(childName){
 this.name= childName; 
   
  }
}</script>`

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing in your `script` section, you're not importing the `Body` component, which is where you are trying to emit an event.

Right now you have this:

```
<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
export default {
  components:{
    'app-header': Header,
    'app-body' : Body
  },
  data () { 
    return  {
      name: 'John', 
    } 
  }, 
  methods: {
    setName(payload) {
      this.name = payload;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

There isn't an `import` statement for the `Body` component, so your parent component doesn't know what `Body` is. To fix this you just need to add an import like you've done for `Header`. It might look like this: `import Body from './components/Body.vue';`

Now that the `Body` component is being used, you need to include it in your `template`. You'll do the same thing you did for `app-header`, and include a tag like this `<app-body></app-body>`. Finally, you need to add the event listener so the parent knows when to run `setName`. This gets added to the `app-body` tag, and will end up looking like this: `<app-body @custom-event-name="setName"></app-body>`